# Accessing debugging website on android device

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I'm attempting to add some mobile device functionality to our company website, a web application project. Normally changes have to be pushed to a GIT server, and then merged by our development lead, which can be several days and if the changes aren't working as intended, it isn't optimal for testing.

To resolve this, I'm attempting to test my local build website (on my computer) on our Android and Apple products (via internal network). I've been trying to follow the instructions [here](https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/allowing-remote-access-to-your-iis-express-service/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202885/how-can-i-change-iis-express-port-for-a-site) with no resolution.

The problem I seem to be having is the applicationHost.config file only has one site and it doesn't seem to be actively affecting my site. I'm using Visual Studio 2005 (Work requirement, we're maintaining .NET framework 3.0), and I couldn't find a way to configure IIS settings from using the ASP.NET Development Server. The applicationHost.config file is as follows:

```
<sites>
    <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
        </application>
        <application path="/tdweb" applicationPool="DefaultAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\_dev\h2ice\dev\src\web\tdweb" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9868:cuhlrich" />
            <binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="808:*" />
            <binding protocol="net.pipe" bindingInformation="*" />
            <binding protocol="net.msmq" bindingInformation="localhost" />
            <binding protocol="msmq.formatname" bindingInformation="localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

Our web.config file has no port configurations in it either. I've spent two days attempting to resolve this issue and I've made zero progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the IIS manager actually had the physical path pointing to the wrong location. Once I corrected that, and started IIS express, I was able to configure Visual Studio to point to the IIS server instead of the dev server. This was accomplished by going to `Website` > `Start Options` and under `Server` selecting the radio button for `User Custom Server` and configuring that to the url configured with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is heading in the same direction in which you are looking for but you can try to view in compatibility mode in your browser. In Google Chrome, while debugging, you can go to developer tools (F12) and then select the toggle device mode (the Phone Icon). I am not sure if this will help with performance bugs related to iOS or Android but it will at least, display layout problems.

Comment: It isn't in this case. I need to be able to test hyperlinks and see if the links behave as expected with apps.

Comment: Just from some quick browsing around, it looks like maybe Google Canary could do what your needing. http://forums.asp.net/t/2008749.aspx?how+to+debug+vb+net+web+app+page+for+a+mobile+apple+or+samsung+