# Visual studio not creating virtual directory

Tags: iis, web-applications, deployment

I am stuck here in deploying my application to the local IIS server.

First of all my system doesn't have IIS manager then I get this by adding features to windows to enable that.

My IIS manager is IIS express 8.0 and using windows 10 with visual studio 2012

Now the problem is:

I created a web application and wants to deploy it in Local IIS server as:
Right click on Project in VS->Properties->Web->and selected local iis server radioButton

But got the error in result as

> The site for the Url.... exists on both local iis web server and the
>   iis express web server. You need to edit the applictionhost.config
>   file to change the port number used by iis express or change the
>   bindings in iis manager.

How can I deploy my application to the local IIS server?

Answer (score 8):

You have to check the URL you are trying to deploy matches a binding in your local IIS.

For example if you are deploying to *http://localMachineName/yourapp* you should have a *WebSite* on *IIS* that has the binding created to

- Hostname:LOCALMACHINE or *
- PORT:80(in this case)

The most common case is that you use *localhost* as server name, so check you have the binding:

- Hostname: localhost or *
- PORT:80(in this case)

In other words, *Visual studio* connects to your *IIS* looking for a binding that should exist.

Also check you execute VS as **administrator**.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a Website binded 80 port.

1. Open IIS manager
2. Right click sites, add website
3. Site Name: Website 
   Pyhsical path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
   Host Name: Leave blank
   IP address: All Unassigned
   Port: 80
4. Open VS as administrator
5. Go to your project properties > web > server > local iis
6. And now click create virtual directory. It's will be work :)

We have created firstly main Website on iis and we created sub website on visual studio has bind it to main Website.

Answer (score 3):

Delete this file in your root project folder (or back it up)

```
.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

Empty the IISUrl tags in your project file (if there is one)

```
<IISUrl></IISUrl>
```

Go to project properties and try to create your virtual url again.

Answer (score 0):

You have two database connections using the same port.

> The site for the Url.... exists on both local iis web server and the
>   iis express web server. You need to edit the applictionhost.config
>   file to change the port number used by iis express or change the
>   bindings in iis manager.

You need to change the port number being used by IIS express. [This  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21202917/3956566) gives good instructions.

Using right mouse clicks on solution explorer. I'm sure you'll have no issue with this. I think this is the easier solution than changing the bindings in your code. But that is another option.