# Enabling https protocol in .NET MVC 5 application for localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, https, iis-10

I'm trying to enable https protcol for my application that I'm building on a localhost which has a port number like this:

```
https://localhost:19590/
```

[image]

I have went to the IIS xx express version and enabled https binding and have been able to access localhost (without any port number) via https like this:

```
https://localhost/
```

But now I need to enable HTTPS for the project solution I'm working on currently on port 19590, and when I try to access it, it says that the:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
```

What am I doing wrong here, how can I enable HTTPS for the localhost project on this port number exactly?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: I saw someone replied, but deleted the reply before I could read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project properties, in the web section under Servers can you try choosing Local IIS instead of IIS Express and create virtual directory on https://localhost/

Comment: Or your question might be a replica of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202885/how-can-i-change-iis-express-port-for-a-site