# DotNet display different port on same local server

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not really familiar with dotnet but need to make some changes to an app built with it. On the app's server, I'm running a Python application on a different port (8050). If I'm in the server and I go to http://127.0.0.1:8050 the Python app displays fine. I'm trying to show the outputs of this via the app written in dot net.

I have a file like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProjectDefault" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="127.0.0.1:8050" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This does not work and the iframe isn't the right approach, but it's roughly what I would like to happen. I want the dot net page to render the content shown on port 8050. Is there any way to make this happen?

The Default.aspx.cs page seems pretty simple too:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class MyProjectDefault : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

if any changes there would help.

Thank you!

Comment: in ,NET, the port is dynamic, so you get a port every time ... use Visual Studio properties in the project to specify a fixed port https://stackoverflow.com/a/21202917/28004

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. `.Net` has nothing to do with it. This is because how `iframe` works. It does not matter where you host it, the url inside the `iframe` is always referred from client machine. So, anyone opening the app is actually looking for `127.0.0.1:8050` on their machine, which does not exist. You can only view this from the server itself, because at that time the target `127.0.0.1:8050` is the server itself.

You will need to host the application with a public domain or at least with a public static ip address that points to the machine hosting the python website. Then use that url inside the iframe.

Having an `iframe` is exactly same as opening a browser and putting that url in the address bar.