# Runing a REST web site from IIS Express returns 404 Not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

Developing a Dotnet Framework 4.8 REST API in VS2019 and starting IIExpress that way is no problem.
`GET http://localhost:51241/api/user` returns correct data.

So I start IIExpress from the command line
but then `GET http://localhost:8080/api/user` returns a 404.
Why?

---

Command line:
`& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe' /path:C:\DATA\Nav\bin\`

`GET http://localhost:8080/` returns a 403.14 (not allowed to browse) which is correct.

---

A clue can be the output:

```
Copied template config file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config' to 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\applicationhost2020130173241776.config'
Updated configuration file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\applicationhost2020130173241776.config' with given cmd line info.
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:8080/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/"
Registration completed
IIS Express is running.
Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express
```

as my site is not called "Development Web Site" but "Nav".
Another clue is that may call results in copies from 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config' while VS2019 seems to use 'C:\DATA\Nav.vs\Nav\config\applicationhost.config'

The `applicationhost.config` file IISExpress copies from, is not the same as VS2019 uses as my, failed, run copies from 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config' but VS2019 seems to use 'C:\DATA\Nav.vs\Nav\config\applicationhost.config'

Comment: It looks like it's ignoring the copied applicationhost.config. Have you looked at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202885/how-can-i-change-iis-express-port-for-a-site

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line#running-a-site-using-iis-express-from-the-command-line You must use an explicit `/config` switch, and also point to `C:\DATA\Nav.vs\Nav\config\applicationhost.config` as VS does. The issue you observed was caused by the fact that IIS Express without `/config` switch loads its own default config file, which does not contain your site at all.

Comment: Your kind words and a dinner and some brain cool down time made me read the docs properly again and realise that the `/config:` flag was for the `applicationhost.config` and not the the site's config. So calling `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe' /config:C:\DATA\Nav\.vs\Nav\config\applicationhost.config /site:Nav` made it work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part to simulate VS launching IIS Express is that you must call IIS Express command line with the correct `/config` switch pointing to the `applicationHost.config` file generated by VS (hidden in `.vs` folder, for VS2015 and above).

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line#running-a-site-using-iis-express-from-the-command-line)